# Vision based Augmented Reality Objective-C library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality

I'm looking for an Objective-C library / or just help in building a vision-based augmented reality application that does not rely on visual markers.

[Qualcomm](http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/augmented-reality)'s is perfect, but only on Android (iOS is coming, but not soon enough). Any body know any other similar libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QCAR for iOS has recently been released into public beta.

Comment: any new updates on this? Is this still the most realiable one?

Answer (score 1):

The only one I'm aware of is [String](http://www.poweredbystring.com), and I've become aware of that only via this [iPhone + Kinect AR video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8tiHXDiqsw) (YouTube link) that recently did the rounds. So I've no direct experience of using it and no opinion on it, but I nevertheless think it qualifies as an answer to your question. It's commercial, but I think Qualcomm's is too.

Comment: Thanks for the String link, I had forgotten about those guys. They use markers though, I kinda need a visual pickup.

Comment: Oh, you're right. In my mind I had conflated visual training (because I think Qualcomm require a particular image or subset of the image to be present, and position relative to the whole image is calculated) with markers. I apologise.

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin Loulier created a [VRToolKit](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/5-virtual-reality-on-iphone-code-inside) sample application for the iPhone that is based on the ARToolKitPlus framework.  This sample uses the framework to track specific markers within the environment and allows you to overlay objects on them.  I've seen some even more impressive demonstrations of this framework for using the camera to augment reality.

However, the ARToolKit framework (the parent of ARToolKitPlus) is by default available under the GPL license, which generally makes it incompatible with the App Store (and with commercial applications in general).  You can purchase a commercial-use license for this framework from ARToolworks, if you need to use this within a non-GPL application.

Additionally, you might look into OpenCV for recognizing and tracking features in the environment.  I've heard reports of people getting fairly decent performance out of it on iOS devices, even for more complex operations.

I've done some [limited work](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios) myself in processing the video from the iPhone camera using the GPU, but nothing like what ARToolKit or OpenCV provides.

Comment: It needs to be Vision-based not Marker-based (like VRToolkit). OpenCV is where Ive found alot of good Vision-based work, but very little Objective-C / iPhone libraries / discussion.

Comment: @daidai - Technically, finding markers in the environment is still vision-based augmented reality, but yes, if you want to do more generic processing of input video something like OpenCV is more appropriate.  You could also look at what I've started with some of the GPU-based video processing I'm doing for more performant recognition.  Be aware that what you're asking for is extremely difficult (which is why machine vision is the focus of many research groups), so you're not going to find easy, drop-in solutions.  You'll need to do some legwork yourself.

Comment: @daidai - Also, there's plenty of work that's been done to use OpenCV on the iPhone, as evidenced by the number of questions and answers about it here on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biphone%5D+%2Bopencv

Comment: The GPL is not necessarily incompatible with the App Store; it just means people can rip off your code (but if people do and try to sell it on the App Store without any modifications, you can probably get Apple to take it down for not being "novel").

Comment: @tc - Rémi Denis-Courmont would seem to believe that GPLv2 is incompatible with the App Store: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/01/vlc-for-ios-vanishes-2-months-after-eruption-of-gpl-dispute.ars , as does the FSF: http://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/more-about-the-app-store-gpl-enforcement

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Aurasma http://www.aurasma.com/?  They let you build custom apps with their system, which might suit your needs.