# take multiple pictures and edit them forming video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

Can you auto take multiple pictures and then edit them in real time for an iphone app? Like say u want to make a video of a man and add a beard to him can you do it while streaming? the mustach moves according to where his face is detected and say take about 5-15 frames per second?

Comment: This is really broad. If you have a more specific question, feel free to ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can.

It would involve tracking some facial features or markers added for the purpose at the least. However this is such a vast and complex field, you'll hardly get a single advice here that will get you going.

If you really mean it, I'd suggest looking for Augmented Reality libraries, there's a few out there. Most of them work by tracking a special pattern and not arbitrary features though, so be prepared for a **big** load of work.

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687339/416600) for a first few hints, you'll find more information on the topic easily through the search engine of your choice.